# Как определить есть ли в потоке данные для чтения?

Tags: php, websocket, потоки-данных

```html
<?php
echo "try to start...<br />";
$socket = stream_socket_server("tcp://127.0.0.1:8889", $errno, $errstr);

if (!$socket) {
    echo "socket unavailable<br />";
    die($errstr. "(" .$errno. ")\n");
}


$connects = array();
while (true) {
    echo "main while...<br />";
    //формируем массив прослушиваемых сокетов:
    $read = $connects;
    $read [] = $socket;
    $write = $except = null;

    if (!stream_select($read, $write, $except, null)) {//ожидаем сокеты доступные для чтения (без таймаута)
        break;
    }

    if (in_array($socket, $read)) {
    /*условие в любом случае будет true $socket либо имеет соединение либо нет, но в любом случае существует в массиве read*/

        //принимаем новое соединение(если есть) и производим рукопожатие:
        if (($connect = stream_socket_accept($socket, 0)) && $info = handshake($connect)) {
            echo "new connection...<br />";            
            echo "connect=".$connect.", info=".$info."<br />OK<br />";    

            $connects[] = $connect;//добавляем его в список необходимых для обработки
            onOpen($connect, $info);//вызываем пользовательский сценарий
        }
        unset($read[ array_search($socket, $read) ]);
    }

    foreach($read as $connect) {//обрабатываем все соединения
        $data = fread($connect, 100000);
        if (!$data) { //соединение было закрыто
            echo "connection closed...<br />";    
            fclose($connect);
            unset($connects[ array_search($connect, $connects) ]);
            onClose($connect);//вызываем пользовательский сценарий
            continue;
        }
        onMessage($connect, $data);//вызываем пользовательский сценарий*/
        //ВОТ ФУНКЦИЯ В СЛУЧАЕ ОТСУТСТВИЯ НОВЫХ ДАННЫХ В ПОТОКЕ
        onSend($connect, "снова привет");
        $q = decode($data);
        if ($q['payload'] == 'off'){
            fclose($socket);
            exit("УБИЛО");}
        }

}
function onMessage($connect, $data) {
    $f = decode($data);
    echo "Message:";
    echo $f['payload'] . "<br />\n";
    fwrite($connect, encode($f['payload']));
}
function onSend($connect, $string) {
    fwrite($connect, encode($string));
}
```

Есть самодельный веб-сокет сервер на PHP. Все работает и соединения принимает, но возникли сложности с чтением записанных в поток данных, не понимаю как работает функция fread().
Первое: почему она блокирует итерацию цикла если клиент ничего не записывал в поток, однако если хотя бы один из подключенных клиентов что-то записал цикл foreach успешно отработает по всем соединениям и возвращается в прежний режим "ожидания".
Второе: как сделать чтобы foreach отрабатывал без остановок, в случае, если есть что то новое в потоке, отвечал клиенту тем же, записывая это обратно функцией fwrite(), если нету нового, то записывал строку от сервера, например "снова привет" также функцией fwrite()?
P.S. функции кодирования, раскодирования, рукопожатия приводить не буду, думаю будет лишним для вопроса.
Если в чем то неправ буду рад поправкам и ссылкам на подробные описания работы всего что связано с потоками и веб-сокетами в целом с опорой на php.